# How do we know the Quran will never change while we consider the Bible as corrupted and manipulated?

Tags: quran, bible

God assured us that his holy book the Quran will never be changed or altered, now does this stand for all of the holy books God has revealed through the prophets, or is it only for the Quran?

In conversation with the fellow Christians, we always refer to the Bible as corrupted and manipulated (Vatican city proves this), and we as Muslims explain how the Quran will remain unchanged until the day of judgment and we have been assured so by God and his prophet.

Answer (score 3):

No, we are clearly told that the Qura'an will never change.

BUT the same have not been said about the other books. We have also been told we cannot believe OR disbelieve anything in the other holy books because we don't know what is the truth and what is not the truth in them. But overall, they are the predecessors to the Qura'an and we should work by what the Qura'an tells us.

Moreover, when the Qura'an came, it overruled the other books. Therefore, you should abide by the rules of the Qura'an and not any other book. Nevertheless, you **MUST** respect the other books.

Think about it like rules and regulations in airports: 20 years ago you were allowed to take liquids and a number of other things on to the plane. Now you have so many more restrictions.

That does not mean the old law was changed that is why we dont believe it. It just means the previous regulations are not sufficient for today and we have to abide by new ones (This does not mean I agree or disagree with either of these laws of airport).

Comment: How do you prove to a non-muslim which of course doesn't believe the Quran is from God, that God will make sure the Quran never will change -therefore it will never change? In non-muslims point of view this will be circular reasoning and a bad argument.